# Как программно задать отступы элементу TableLayout?

Tags: java, android

Делаю генерацию сетки. Подобие игрового поля. С этим кодом не делаются отступы, а, наоборот, всё исчезает.

```
private void GrdidGenerate() {
    for (int i = 0; i < LevelGrid[pos]; i++) {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ));
        for (int j = 0; j < LevelGrid[pos]; j++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
            params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_btn_radio_material);
            imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));
            tableRow.addView(imageView, j);
        }
        grid.addView(tableRow, i);
    }
}
```

Если убрать этот кусок кода, то отступы не появляются, но зато всё не исчезает.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: мне кажется проблема кроется здесь `(int i = 0; i < LevelGrid[pos]; i++) {`
и `(int j = 0; j < LevelGrid[pos]; j++)`. исправьте на `(int i = 0; i > LevelGrid[pos]; i++) {` и `(int j = 0; j < LevelGrid[pos]; j++)`. Правда я не уверен.

Comment: @Insider, нет, проблема не в этом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-моему это типовая ошибка, вы неверно указали тип параметра разметки. Если вы объект добавляете в `TableRow`, то причем тут `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(100, 100);
params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);                    
tableRow.addView(imageView, j);
```

Comment: Блин, точно, спасибо огромное!

Comment: Да пожалуйста, как-то давно, тоже долго не мог найти в чем баг, в подобной ситуации.